# How do I get my Logo to overlay the blue banner?

Tags: html, css

[image: How do I get my Logo to overlay the blue banner?]

Can someone please help me how to overlay my globe logo over my blue horizontal bar? Thanks! I have attached a photo of how it looks. I do not want to lose the positioning or anything.

CSS

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: arial;
} 

#bannerTitle {
    background: steelblue;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    background: linear-gradient(steelblue, steelblue, white);
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="logo" src="img/globe.png" alt="">
    <h1 class="title">The Inter<span>net</span></h1>
        <div id="bannerTitle">
            <h2>The World Wide Web</h2>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp 

You need to add z-index

```
#bannerTitle{
background: steelblue;
height: 60px;
position: relative;
margin-top: -50px;
background: linear-gradient(steelblue,
steelblue, white);
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as matti said; you need to consider the `z-index` variable. What `z-index` does is relayer elements within the same stacking context.

From your HTML markup, I can see that your `<img>` and `<div id="bannerTitle">` are sibling elements, so they are within the same stacking context. Therefore, whoever has a higher `z-index` will display on top of the other.

One way to do that is to demote the "bannerTitle" div, as matti did: `z-index:-1`.

An alternative way is to promote the `<img>`: `.logo { z-index:99; }`.

It's good to know that `z-index` only applies to block elements, and `img` is `inline` by default, but you're already made it a block element with `inline-block`.